# Django jQuery AJAX Self Replacing Script

Tags: jquery, django

I've been having trouble implementing a self-replacing script. I admit that I am terribly confused.

I am trying to implement two buttons such that if you click on one, a POST request is sent to the server; the server validates that you indeed went to this webpage and sends back a HttpResponseRedirect to a page containing an incomplete web-page/a page that has only the portions I want updated after the button is clicked. Once my orginal jQuery request receives that new page, it will replace the elements on current the page with the new one it just received.

My jQuery looks like:

```
<script id="self_replacing">
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#button1').click(function(){
    $.post("/", { 
      unique_id : "{{ unique_id }}",
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    function(data){
       var js_portion = $('<div/>').html(data).find('self_replacing')
       var html_portion = $('<div/>').html(data).find('pic_content')
       $('#pic_content').replaceWith(html_portion)
       $('#self_replacing').replaceWith(js_portion)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Incomplete Page:

```
<script id="self_replacing">
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#button1').click(function(){
    $.post("/", { 
      unique_id : "{{ unique_id }}",
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    function(data){
       var js_portion = $('<div/>').html(data).find('self_replacing')
       var html_portion = $('<div/>').html(data).find('pic_content')
       $('#pic_content').replaceWith(html_portion)
       $('#self_replacing').replaceWith(js_portion)
    });
  });
});
</script>
<div id="pic_content">
      .
      .

</div>
```

Do I have the right idea? When I watch my requests through the FireBug console, the traffic begins scaling upward everytime the button is clicked.

For instance at the start, it beings with 1 click = 1 POST
then 1 click = 2POST, and then 1 click = 3 POST. I'm not too sure why this is happening. Is there something wrong with my jQuery script?

Note: The jQuery script needs to be updated after each POST too.

Comment: `$('self_replacing').replaceWith(js_portion)` should be `$('#self_replacing').replaceWith(js_portion)` and `$('pic_content').replaceWith(html_portion)` should be `$('#pic_content').replaceWith(html_portion)`

Comment: thanks for the catch :) However, the issue is still the same multiple GETs for one HttpRedirect and now no text is showing up where the text was supposed to be replaced.

Comment: FireFox Console: POST http://127.0.0.1:8002/
 
302 FOUND
  166ms 
jquery.min.js (line 4)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8002/partial
 
301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
  7ms 
GET http://127.0.0.1:8002/partial/
 
200 OK
  43ms

Comment: why do you need the redirect step? why not just have the view that processes the POST request return the partial that you want to render?